# Cordova Plugin Inside HTML?

Tags: html, cordova, plugins

Is it possible to design or use a Cordova plugin inside (or next to/over) HTML? In other words, I do not want the plugin to be full-screen hiding the HTML app, I still want to show my HTML app, so the plugin is integrated with the HTML.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Cordova plugin merely provides an interface between the Javascript environment in the Webview in which your Cordova app is running, and the native platform on which it is running. I.e. it enables you to invoke native code from within the Javascript of your Cordova app.

> Is it possible to design or use a Cordova plugin inside (or next to/over) HTML?

Most plugins don't obscure the Cordova Webview ("HTML" as you describe it) in which your app is running, they just provide a JS API that your app can call: for example [cordova-plugin-device](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device) enables you to query details about the platform and device on which the app is running.

You should read the [Cordova plugin documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/hybrid/plugins/index.html) for more information.

Comment: I am developing a custom plugin. So, are you saying yes I can partially hide my app WebView with the plugin?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with a plugin - there are no limitations: if you want to "hide" the Cordova Webview, with another native Android Activity / iOS ViewController, that is entirely possible. If you want to mix native UI elements with the Webview layout, that is also possible but not trivial.

Comment: Can you plz direct me to their docs where they explain how to do it?

Comment: The Cordova docs don't give much more that an outline. Your best bet is to find an existing Cordova plugin that has similar functionality to that which you desire, look at the source code, then use it as a template to create your own plugin.